# How to convert fractional inequalities into equivalent integer inequalities?

Tags: differential-equations

The fractional inequality is:

```
(a (x - 1))/(x - 2) > 1
```

How can we convert it into the form of an integer inequality like this:

```
((a - 1) x + 2 - a) (x - 2) > 0
```

I tried the following method, but the parentheses on the left did not handle merging similar items for x

```
SubtractSides[(a (x - 1))/(x - 2) > 1] // Together // Simplify

(2 + a (-1 + x) - x) (-2 + x) > 0
```

And the method above is invalid for converting an inequality with an equal sign to an equivalent integer inequality

```
SubtractSides[(a (x - 1))/(x - 2) >= 1] // Together // Simplify

 (2 + a (-1 + x) - x)/(-2 + x) >= 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

rel1 = (a (x - 1))/(x - 2) > 1;

rel2 = SubtractSides[rel1] // Together // Simplify

(* (2 + a (-1 + x) - x) (-2 + x) > 0 *)

rel3 = ReplacePart[rel2, {1, 1} -> Collect[rel2[[1, 1]], x]]

(* (-2 + x) (2 - a + (-1 + a) x) > 0 *)
```